# Calling another python function in a different Conda environment

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I have to different projects that are running on different Conda environments. Is there a way to call a python function in a different environment and also get a return object?

Comment: No.  You'll need to copy the file into the other project.

Comment: Do you have a solution?